# PyQGIS script for loading several .xyz files into QGIS gives NameError

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console, nameerror

I found a script for loading several csv files into QGIS and modified it for .xyz Data. Yesterday on one Computer it worked and today on a different Computer it's not working anymore.

Is there something wrong with the code?

I tried to use the following code in the python console

```
import glob, os


path = "C:\Users\J\Desktop\xyz_data"

os.chdir(path)

for file in glob.glob("*.xyz"):
    uri = "file:///" + path + file + "?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4647&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (" ", "field_1", "field_2")
    name = file.replace('.xyz', '')
    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, 'delimitedtext')
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

After the "path" line I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource
>       code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
>     File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 168, in **call**
>       return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
>     File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 99, in _maybe_compile
>       raise err1
>     File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 87, in _maybe_compile
>       code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
>     File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 133, in **call**
>       codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
>     File "", line 1
>   SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
>   os.chdir(path)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
>       exec(code, self.locals)
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   NameError: name 'path' is not defined

When I enter the last line of the Code into the python console nothing happens. No layers are uploaded and I don't get error Messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
path = r"C:\Users\J\Desktop\xyz_data"
```

instead of:

```
path = "C:\Users\J\Desktop\xyz_data"
```

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: I've rolled back your question because it appears my answer was correct i.e. when you fixed that the error you were getting no longer occurred.  You can ask a new question for your new error.